# How to know what record I am in? Dynamics AX7

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7

Here is the scenario:

In the `Sales and marketing > Sales orders > All sales orders`

I entered the lines by double-clicking the **Sales order number**

by doing that I am entering the lines of the sales order.

Now in my lines, there is a button there where I will use to add a syntax where I will insert fields in my newly created table.

I would like to know how can I know what record I am in (before entering the lines/before double-clicking the sales order number). I need to know what **Sales order number** I'm in as I enter the lines of the record.

Comment: Could you please explain why you need the sales order number *before* the user double-clicks the order. This would require predictive power.

Also, explain the context where you need the number. Sales order form or class called from sales order form.

Comment: I need the sales order number because I need to know what record I am in. If i know what record I am in then I can obtain the lines of that record. It is in my question.

Comment: You answered the why part, not the where part.

Comment: I need the number for the code I am going to use to input fields from the lines to my newly created table. I need to know what record I am in to get the right lines fields.

Answer (score 1):

In every form the current record of a specific `FormDataSource` has the same name of the `FormDataSource`. For example in the `SalesTableListPage` form the only datasource is called "SalesTable", so the current sales order record is identified in your code with the `salesTable` identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Every record is extended from [`Common`]. There you have field `TableId`. You can get table name with [`tableId2name`].

You can inspect fields with [`DictTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dicttable.aspx) and `field*` methods.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question sir. will update my question